# Jenkins stash from workspace with job

Tags: jenkins

I am trying to move some information from one job to another.

My simplified pipeline looks like this:

```
    stage('SourceStage') {
            steps {
                script {
                    build job: '/SomeFolder/SourceJob', 
                        parameters: [
                            string(name: 'PARAMA', value: 'SomeValue')
                        ]
                }
                dir( '???UNKNOWN???' ) {
                    stash includes: 'MYFILE', name: 'SomeStashName'
                }
            }
        }
        stage('TargetStage') {
            steps {
                dir( '???UNKNOWN???' ) {
                    unstash 'SomeStashName'
                }
                script {
                    build job: '/SomeFolder/TargetJob', 
                        parameters: [
                            string(name: 'PARAMA2', value: 'SomeValue2')
                        ]
                }
            }
        }
```

Inside 'SourceJob' I got a bash script that stores some information into a file.

```
echo "$SomeVariable" > "$WORKSPACE/MYFILE"
```

I can't figure out how to reference the file in the SourceStage correctly - which leads to not being able to find it during unstash.
Follow up question would be - what is the location from inside a bash script in TargetJob when I am finally able to unstash? $WORKSPACE/MYFILE ?

UPDATE: I found out that it seems you can use stash unstash for this kind of data transfer. Instead I converted it to use "env.foobar".